# result of async function getContractData() is not error

Tags: smartcontracts, web3js

I have been developing website integrated metamask as react js
by the way,web3.js is not connected with backend
in my opinioin, backend means contract

transaction was not happend.
result is not success.
api request is failed
I think contract developer developed smart contract.
I can not contact with him.